# Help regarding Android NDK

Tags: android, android-ndk

I am a beginner in using Android NDK.

I am using Eclipse and I installed cygwin to build the c file to generate the .so file

But while building the c file in cygwin I am always getting the error

> make: ***No rule to make target 'file.c' ... .Stop

I tried building different C codes but for every file it says the same error ..

Here is the source code:

```
public class ndktest extends Activity 
{
 static {   
    System.loadLibrary("ndkt");   
   }
 private native void helloLog(String logThis);  
 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    helloLog("this is to test log file");
 }   }
```

file.c

`void Java_com_ndktest_helloLog(JNIEnv * env, jobject this, jstring logThis)

{

      jboolean isCopy;

    const char * szLogThis = (*env)->GetStringUTFChars(env, logThis, &isCopy);

    (*env)->ReleaseStringUTFChars(env, logThis, szLogThis);

}`

And here is my Android.mk

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)   
include $(CLEAR_VARS)   
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog   
LOCAL_MODULE    := ndkt 
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := file.c
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

I searched for the solution for the cause of error ... but nothing works for me.

Can anyone tell me where I am making the mistake ?

Thanks,

Siva Kumar

Comment: Do you have a file named `file.c` in the directory your Android.mk is in?

Comment: yes.. file.c is present in the same folder as Android.mk is in.

Comment: I could solve the "No rule to make file" error in cygwin ... but when i execute the java code it gives UnsatisfiedLinkError and showing the error at the helloLog() function call ...

Comment: One mistake is that you're asking two completely unrelated questions here.  The makefile problem and the link problem have nothing in common.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely the error lies in any of the following two areas:

1. In the function name you have used. See if your package name matches with the function name you have used in the C code.
   Java_com_ndktest_helloLog
2. Verify that the Android.mk file is setting up the right directory to find the C source file in the jni directory.

**This is a great site, to setup your first ndk program.
Very easy to follow and also contains screenshots:
http://mindtherobot.com/blog/452/android-beginners-ndk-setup-step-by-step/**

Answer (score 0):

For your java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError, you need to find out what the full message is.

You'll see the exception at

```
Runtime.loadLibrary(String, ClassLoader) line: 434
```

If you step past that, you'll get to

```
ExceptionInInitializerError.<init>(Throwable) line: 59
```

Now you can see the contents of the exception, and it'll look something like:

> java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Cannot
>   load library: reloc_library[1311]: 
>   1281 cannot locate
>   'somethingInterestingWouldBeHere'...

And that should help figure out what's wrong.

Keep in mind that you have to manually figure out the load order for your libraries; if library A depends on library B, you need to load B, then A.  That doesn't happen automatically.